# Parameter passing through classes C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am fairly new to C#, and i have a problem where I try to pass some variable from one class to another.

I have a business layer, where i am gathering the variables and telling them where to go, and i also have a UI layer where i want to activate that method when a button is click.

*UILayer:*

```
private void btnLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BusinessLayer BUS = new BusinessLayer();
    BUS.InsertLog(dunno how to reference variables here);
}
```

*BusinessLayer:*

```
public void InsertLog(int CustomerId,
                      DateTime DateLogged,
                      string CustomerRef,
                      int AssignedEmployeeId,
                      string Description,
                      int ImpactId,
                      string RootCause,
                      string RootFix,
                      int StatusId,
                      DateTime FixDate,
                      float TimeUsed,
                      string InternalRef)
{
    DataLayer dao = new DataLayer();

    dao.CommandSqlStatement("INSERT Region (CustomerId,
                                            DateLogged,
                                            CustomerRef,
                                            AssignedEmployeeId,
                                            Description,
                                            ImpactId,
                                            ImpactBrief,
                                            RootCause,
                                            RootFix,
                                            StatusId,
                                            FixDate,
                                            TimeUsed,
                                            InternalRef) " +
                            "VALUES (" + CustomerId + ", " + 
                                         DateLogged + ", '" +
                                         CustomerRef + "', " +
                                         AssignedEmployeeId + ", '" +
                                         Description + "', " +
                                         ImpactId + ", '" +
                                         RootCause + "', '" +
                                         RootFix + "', " +
                                         StatusId + ", " +
                                         FixDate + ", " +
                                         TimeUsed + ", '" +
                                         InternalRef);
}
```

I just want to know how to reference the variables in the UILayer, because i have tried several ways and cant seem to figure it out,
Can anyone help?

Comment: Obviously this code may be altered for SO but just in case it's not this has a clear SQL Injection vulnerability in it; you cna learn more here https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: What variables are you trying to reference? The only variables you have in the `btnLog_Click` method are `sender` and `e`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all those values are available to you in the UILayer so then you just put the values of all the parameters from the InsertLog method into the call to the method

```
private void btnLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BusinessLayer BUS = new BusinessLayer();
    BUS.InsertLog(CostumerId, dateLogged, costumerRef, etc);
}
```

If you don't have those values in the UILayer yet you just need to get them from somewhere. Which depends on where you are assigning them.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question I will make some assumption to understand the problem. You have a form with controls like `TextBox` etc. that have the values for the `Log` OR if not you are aware what values need to pass to the `InsertLog` method. Then you can simply call the method, and pass on the required parameters.

To get the values from controls you can do like -

```
BUS.InsertLog(txtBoxCostumerId.Text, /*more parameters */)
```

OR directly the value like -

```
BUS.InsertLog(costumerId /*more parameters */)
```

**Notes** -

1. It is suggested not to use values directly in SQL queries, use `Parameters` instead, as they are prone to SQL Injection
2. There should not be too many parameters, as with your business class, limit your parameters to tw0 or three max, and if required more than that use DTO objects instead

Answer (score 0):

First, declare in your class the list of variables that you want to pass to the BL:

```
    int CustomerId, AssignedEmployeeId, ImpactId, StatusId;
    string InternalRef, CustomerRef, Description, RootCause, RootFix;
    DateTime DateLogged, FixDate;                         
    float TimeUsed;
```

Then, write a method for assigning the value you need to each of the variables:

```
   private void bindDataBeforeSending()
   {
      CustomerRef = Request.Form["CustomerId"]; // for example
      ...
   }
```

Then, call the method passing the variables in the correct order:

```
     private void btnLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindDataBeforeSending();

        BusinessLayer BUS = new BusinessLayer();      
        BUS.InsertLog(CustomerId,DateLogged,CustomerRef,AssignedEmployeeId,Description,ImpactId,RootCause,RootFix,StatusId,FixDate,TimeUsed,InternalRef);
    }
```

If the UI and the BL belong to two different projects, be sure to include the BL in the UI References.